# adding a column with a factor variable that has conditions in R?

Tags: r

I have a date frame transformed into a tibble called 'grades_A2' that has a column called 'grades' for each person's grade and I want to add a new column that has a factor variable that says "lower" if the value of the person's grade is lower than the average which is 75.8 and it says "higher" if the person's grade is higher than the average.

Comment: data.table solution

library(data.table)
```setDT(grades_A2)
grades_A2[grades < 75.8, newcolumn := "lower"]
grades_A2[grades > 75.8, newcolumn := "higher"]```

Comment: tidyverse solution `library(tidyverse); mutate(grades_A2, newcolumn =ifelse(grades <75.8, "lower","higher"))`